# How to retrieve validation rules with source:retrieve in salesforce dx

Tags: salesforcedx

I wanted to know, is it possible to retrieve validation rule using the source:retrieve command in Salesforce DX the same way I use to retrieve classes with source:retrieve -m ApexClass:MyClass -u myOrgAlias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, here is an example

```
 sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ValidationRule:Lead.Rep_Code_Validation
```

it is case sensitive

More info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_validationformulas.htm